# Is it possible to purchase multiple items (managed product ) at single time using In-app billing version 3 in android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am able to purchase one item at single time using in-app billing version 3. But I have no idea to purchase multiple in-app product at single time. Because we can't put one or more purchase request in loop due to it return result in onStartActivityResult().

So, If anyone have idea.Please suggest me.Thanks in advance...